# Python multiprocessing - How to release memory when a process is done?

Tags: python, memory, multiprocessing

I encountered a weird problem while using python multiprocessing library.

My code is sketched below: I spawn a process for each "symbol, date" tuple. I combine the results afterwards.

I expect that when a process has done computing for a "symbol, date" tuple, it should release its memory? apparently that's not the case. I see dozens of processes (though I set the process pool to have size 7) that are suspended¹ in the machine. They consume no CPU, and they don't release the memory.

How do I let a process release its memory, after it has done its computation?

Thanks!

¹ by "suspended" I mean their status in ps command is shown as "S+"

```
def do_one_symbol( symbol, all_date_strings ):
    pool = Pool(processes=7)
    results = [];
    for date in all_date_strings:
        res = pool.apply_async(work, [symbol, date])
        results.append(res);

    gg = mm = ss = 0;
    for res in results:
        g, m, s = res.get()
        gg += g; 
        mm += m; 
        ss += s;
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Did you try to close pool by using [`pool.close`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.close) and then wait for process to finish by [`pool.join`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.join), because if parent process keeps on running and does not wait for child processes they will become [zombies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process)

Comment: This was the root cause of my script caused node reboot due to >90% of 4Gb memory were consumed :) Thank You!

Answer (score 23):

Try setting the maxtasksperchild argument on the pool.  If you don't, then the process is reusued over and over again by the pool so the memory is never released.  When set, the process will be allowed to die and a new one created in it's place.  That will effectively clean up the memory.

I guess it's new in 2.7:  http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool

Comment: I have been using this approach, works fine. Question is, why doesn't it release memory? Or maybe not fast enough...??

Comment: This completely solved my problem, thanks @user1914881

Answer (score 4):

You should probably call `close()` followed by `wait()` on your `Pool` object.

http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool

> `join()`
>   Wait for the worker processes to exit. One must call close() or terminate() before using join().