# Why python script works perfectly when run manually but throws MemoryError when run via Task Schedule?

Tags: python, out-of-memory, windows-task-scheduler

I have a python script that runs without any problem when I run it via command line or through an editor. However, once I set it up to run automatically via Task Scheduler, I am getting MemoryErrors in my logs.

This is the error message:

> MemoryError: Unable to allocate 2.03 MiB for an array with shape (10252, 52) and data type object

[image]

Comment: did u set 1 or 2 seconds time.sleep?

Comment: I will try. Thanks. Could you elaborate on why pausing the script for a second or two might solve the problem? @CYREX

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34876536/13824946

Comment: @CYREX If I understand it correctly, the thread you sent me is describing a situation when time.sleep() is actually causing memory leaks. I am not sure how it can prevent them. Any idea?

Comment: basing on your error message you have to deal with threads and time.sleep  because launching the entire job results in memory leak or no memory at all. so you have to read by 1000 lines for each thread, once the first thread finished reading 1000 lines, it will be slept or process killed then the second thread start to do the job and so on. this is what i meant.

Comment: I have tried time.sleep(arg) and gc.collect() in vain. Does anyone have other tips what might be wrong? Other scripts run well via Task Scheduler. It is just this one. @CYREX

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-different-ways-to-kill-a-thread/amp/

Answer (score 0):

I have not solved my question directly but still I have a solution that might be handy for some people.

At the end, I gave up on Task Schedule and instead created a new Python script which runs all my Python scripts at a specific time. The library is called Schedule.

```
import schedule
from MODULE_1 import FUNCTION_1  
from MODULE_2 import FUNCTION_2 

schedule.every().monday.at(13:20).do(FUNCTION_1)
schedule.every().monday.at(20:10).do(FUNCTION_2) 

while True:
    try:
        schedule.run_pending()
    except Exception as f: 
        e = datetime.datetime.now()
        print(e.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
        print("ERROR TYPE:")
        print(f) 
    time.sleep(1)
```