# Can we use multiprocessing in threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-2.7, multiprocessing

In python 2/3 is it possible to run multiprocessing in threads?

And how to set multiprocessing to auto release the memory used by process after it has completed execution, without command `join()` if I don't need to wait or take some value from process?

I found this Scoot S trick:

```
def easy_parallize(f, sequence):
    from multiprocessing import Pool
    pool = Pool(processes=8)
    result = pool.map(f, sequence)
    cleaned = [x for x in result if not x is None]
    cleaned = asarray(cleaned)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return cleaned
```

But there are 2 problems here:

1. It still uses `join()`, and it makes the main program wait for the process to finish before continuing.
2. I'm unsure what's done to clear the process from memory (I'm a newbie to linux commands and don't know how to make sure).

Comment: The memory used by a sub-process started via `multiprocessing` will automatically be released when it's finished running. Using `join()` just determines whether the current task blocks while waiting for that to happen (or continues its own execution without waiting).

Comment: in first i think like that.. but what are this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7650252/9027607

Comment: The example you are posting is blocking on `map` and is collecting the results (which is a blocking operation as well). Can you better clarify what are you trying to achieve?