# Memory not freed after Python's multiprocessing Pool is finished

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, multiprocessing

When having used Python's multiprocessing `Pool.map()`, I do not get back my memory. 
Over 1GB of memory is still occupied, although the function with the `Pool` is exited, everything is closed, and I even try to delete the variable of the `Pool` and explicitly call the garbage collector.

When, in the code shown below, un-commenting the two lines above the `pool.map()` (and commenting the `pool.map()` line) everything looks OK, but as soon as using `multiprocessing` the memory seems not to get freed again after leaving the function.

Because in the real world code several other functions using `multiprocessing` are called, this then even stacks up, consuming all the memory. 
(Unfortunately I can not produce a minimal example for the minor second case, with stacking up the memory, but as soon as the main problem is solved this second one should be gone also.)

This is Python 3.7.3 on Linux and any help for at least *explaining* or even solving this issue is very welcome.

Minimal example code:

```
import gc
from time import sleep
from memory_profiler import profile
import numpy as np

def waitat(where, t):
    # print and wait, gives chance to see live memory usage in some task manager program
    print(where)
    sleep(t)

@profile
def parallel_convert_all_to_hsv(imgs: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    from skimage.color import rgb2hsv
    import multiprocessing as mp
    print("going parallel")
    pool = mp.Pool()
    try:
        # images_converted = [] # there is no memory problem when using commented lines below, instead of pool.map(…) line
        # for img in imgs:
        #     images_converted.append(rgb2hsv(img))
        images_converted = pool.map(rgb2hsv, imgs)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pool.terminate()
    waitat("after pool.map",5)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    waitat("before del pool",5)
    pool = None
    del pool    # memory should now be freed here?
    mp = None
    rgb2hsv = None

    waitat("after del pool",5)
    print("copying over")
    res = np.array(images_converted)
    waitat("before del image_hsv in function",5)
    images_converted = None
    del images_converted
    return res

@profile
def doit():
    print("create random images")
    max_images = 700
    images = np.random.rand(max_images, 300, 300,3)

    waitat("before going parallel",5)
    images_converted = parallel_convert_all_to_hsv(images)
    print("images_converted has %i bytes" % images_converted.nbytes)
    # how to clean up Pool's memory at latest here?

    waitat("before deleting original images",5)
    images = None
    del images
    waitat("memory should be as before going parallel + %i bytes" % images_converted.nbytes ,10)
    images_converted = None
    del images_converted
    waitat("nearly end, memory should be as before" ,15)
    gc.collect(2)
    waitat("end, memory should be as before" ,15)    

doit()
```

Output with using [Memory Profiler](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/), showing the problem:

```shell
$ python3 -m memory_profiler pool-mem-probs.py
create random images
before going parallel
going parallel
after pool.map
before del pool
after del pool
copying over
before del image_hsv in function
Filename: pool-mem-probs.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    11   1481.2 MiB   1481.2 MiB   @profile
    12                             def parallel_convert_all_to_hsv(imgs: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    13   1487.2 MiB      6.0 MiB       from skimage.color import rgb2hsv
    14   1487.2 MiB      0.0 MiB       import multiprocessing as mp
    15   1487.2 MiB      0.0 MiB       print("going parallel")
    16   1488.6 MiB      1.4 MiB       pool = mp.Pool()
    17   1488.6 MiB      0.0 MiB       try:
    18                                     # images_converted = []  # there is no memory problem when using commented lines below, instead of pool.map(…) line
    19                                     # for img in imgs:
    20                                     #     images_converted.append(rgb2hsv(img))
    21   2930.9 MiB   1442.3 MiB           images_converted = pool.map(rgb2hsv, imgs)
    22                                 except KeyboardInterrupt:
    23                                     pool.terminate()
    24   2930.9 MiB      0.0 MiB       waitat("after pool.map",5)
    25                                 
    26   2930.9 MiB      0.0 MiB       pool.close()
    27   2931.0 MiB      0.1 MiB       pool.join()
    28                                 
    29   2931.0 MiB      0.0 MiB       waitat("before del pool",5)
    30   2931.0 MiB      0.0 MiB       pool = None
    31   2931.0 MiB      0.0 MiB       del pool    # memory should now be freed here?
    32   2931.0 MiB      0.0 MiB       mp = None
    33   2931.0 MiB      0.0 MiB       rgb2hsv = None
    34                                 
    35   2931.0 MiB      0.0 MiB       waitat("after del pool",5)
    36   2931.0 MiB      0.0 MiB       print("copying over")
    37   4373.0 MiB   1441.9 MiB       res = np.array(images_converted)
    38   4373.0 MiB      0.0 MiB       waitat("before del image_hsv in function",5)
    39   4016.6 MiB      0.0 MiB       images_converted = None
    40   4016.6 MiB      0.0 MiB       del images_converted
    41   4016.6 MiB      0.0 MiB       return res


images_converted has 1512000000 bytes
before deleting original images
memory should be as before going parallel + 1512000000 bytes
nearly end, memory should be as before
end, memory should be as before
Filename: pool-mem-probs.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    43     39.1 MiB     39.1 MiB   @profile
    44                             def doit():
    45     39.1 MiB      0.0 MiB       print("create random images")
    46     39.1 MiB      0.0 MiB       max_images = 700
    47   1481.2 MiB   1442.1 MiB       images = np.random.rand(max_images, 300, 300,3)
    48                             
    49   1481.2 MiB      0.0 MiB       waitat("before going parallel",5)
    50   4016.6 MiB   2535.4 MiB       images_converted = parallel_convert_all_to_hsv(images)
    51   4016.6 MiB      0.0 MiB       print("images_converted has %i bytes" % images_converted.nbytes)
    52                                 # how to clean up Pool's memory at latest here?
    53                             
    54   4016.6 MiB      0.0 MiB       waitat("before deleting original images",5)
    55   2574.6 MiB      0.0 MiB       images = None
    56   2574.6 MiB      0.0 MiB       del images
    57   2574.6 MiB      0.0 MiB       waitat("memory should be as before going parallel + %i bytes" % images_converted.nbytes ,10)
    58   1132.7 MiB      0.0 MiB       images_converted = None
    59   1132.7 MiB      0.0 MiB       del images_converted
    60   1132.7 MiB      0.0 MiB       waitat("nearly end, memory should be as before" ,15)
    61   1132.7 MiB      0.0 MiB       gc.collect(2)
    62   1132.7 MiB      0.0 MiB       waitat("end, memory should be as before" ,15)
```

Output of non-parallel code (where the problem does not occur):

```shell
$ python3 -m memory_profiler pool-mem-probs.py
create random images
before going parallel
going parallel
after pool.map
before del pool
after del pool
copying over
before del image_hsv in function
Filename: pool-mem-probs.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    11   1481.3 MiB   1481.3 MiB   @profile
    12                             def parallel_convert_all_to_hsv(imgs: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    13   1488.1 MiB      6.8 MiB       from skimage.color import rgb2hsv
    14   1488.1 MiB      0.0 MiB       import multiprocessing as mp
    15   1488.1 MiB      0.0 MiB       print("going parallel")
    16   1488.7 MiB      0.6 MiB       pool = mp.Pool()
    17   1488.7 MiB      0.0 MiB       try:
    18   1488.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           images_converted = []    # there is no memory problem when using commented lines below, instead of pool.map(…) line
    19   2932.6 MiB      0.0 MiB           for img in imgs:
    20   2932.6 MiB      2.2 MiB               images_converted.append(rgb2hsv(img))
    21                                     # images_converted = pool.map(rgb2hsv, imgs)
    22                                 except KeyboardInterrupt:
    23                                     pool.terminate()
    24   2932.6 MiB      0.0 MiB       waitat("after pool.map",5)
    25                                 
    26   2932.6 MiB      0.0 MiB       pool.close()
    27   2932.8 MiB      0.2 MiB       pool.join()
    28                                 
    29   2932.8 MiB      0.0 MiB       waitat("before del pool",5)
    30   2932.8 MiB      0.0 MiB       pool = None
    31   2932.8 MiB      0.0 MiB       del pool    # memory should now be freed here?
    32   2932.8 MiB      0.0 MiB       mp = None
    33   2932.8 MiB      0.0 MiB       rgb2hsv = None
    34                                 
    35   2932.8 MiB      0.0 MiB       waitat("after del pool",5)
    36   2932.8 MiB      0.0 MiB       print("copying over")
    37   4373.3 MiB   1440.5 MiB       res = np.array(images_converted)
    38   4373.3 MiB      0.0 MiB       waitat("before del image_hsv in function",5)
    39   2929.6 MiB      0.0 MiB       images_converted = None
    40   2929.6 MiB      0.0 MiB       del images_converted
    41   2929.6 MiB      0.0 MiB       return res


images_converted has 1512000000 bytes
before deleting original images
memory should be as before going parallel + 1512000000 bytes
nearly end, memory should be as before
end, memory should be as before
Filename: pool-mem-probs.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    43     39.2 MiB     39.2 MiB   @profile
    44                             def doit():
    45     39.2 MiB      0.0 MiB       print("create random images")
    46     39.2 MiB      0.0 MiB       max_images = 700
    47   1481.3 MiB   1442.1 MiB       images = np.random.rand(max_images, 300, 300,3)
    48                             
    49   1481.3 MiB      0.0 MiB       waitat("before going parallel",5)
    50   2929.6 MiB   1448.3 MiB       images_converted = parallel_convert_all_to_hsv(images)
    51   2929.6 MiB      0.0 MiB       print("images_converted has %i bytes" % images_converted.nbytes)
    52                                 # how to clean up Pool's memory at latest here?
    53                             
    54   2929.6 MiB      0.0 MiB       waitat("before deleting original images",5)
    55   1487.7 MiB      0.0 MiB       images = None
    56   1487.7 MiB      0.0 MiB       del images
    57   1487.7 MiB      0.0 MiB       waitat("memory should be as before going parallel + %i bytes" % images_converted.nbytes ,10)
    58     45.7 MiB      0.0 MiB       images_converted = None
    59     45.7 MiB      0.0 MiB       del images_converted
    60     45.7 MiB      0.0 MiB       waitat("nearly end, memory should be as before" ,15)
    61     45.7 MiB      0.0 MiB       gc.collect(2)
    62     45.7 MiB      0.0 MiB       waitat("end, memory should be as before" ,15)
```

Comment: You may take a look at this response https://stackoverflow.com/a/13946429/9799292

Comment: I don't think that applies, here the pool is closed, joined, and even del'd at the end.

Comment: @Jaleks I've tried taking a look with some of the basic memory tooling (objgraph, pympler) to try and look for uncleared caches or broken C-level refcounts but nothing came up. Ran on 3.8.1 as 3.7 and below have known leaks whose fix may not have been backported. I'd recommend pinging the core team either on IRC (#python-dev) or on the bug tracker.

Comment: try checking the reference count:  `import sys, gc`
 `sys.getrefcount(pool)` . also `gc.get_threshold()`

Comment: @ShpielMeister: how can there be a refcount, if the object is set to None and del'ed? How would the threshold influence the explicit `gc.collect(2)`

Comment: @ShpielMeister note that there is no difference in the code being run or the GC invocations (most of which I expect are defensive to try and fix the issue) between sequential and multiprocessing, there's indeed a problem specifically with multiprocessing. Locally I also tried a threaded pool in place of the multiprocess one, and the issue doesn't arise either.

Comment: @Jaleks reference cycles may be in play: `29.11. gc — Garbage Collector interface
This module provides an interface to the optional garbage collector. It provides the ability to disable the collector, tune the collection frequency, and set debugging options. It also provides access to unreachable objects that the collector found but cannot free. Since the collector supplements the reference counting already used in Python, you can disable the collector if you are sure your program does not create reference cycles. Automatic collection can be disabled by calling gc.disable().`

Answer (score 4):

The generation threshold may be getting in the way, take a look at
    gc.get_threshold()

try including

```
gc.disable()
```

Comment: At which point of the code you did have success, when adding that line?

Comment: Look at the the return value of gc.collect(generation) for generation  0 1 2.  The number of unreachable objects found is returned.

Comment: I'm wondering, is this a solution, or a work around? There seems to be no reason why garbage collection shouldn't just work here, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, there is a leak problem, but it does not appear for some magical parameters. I could not understand it, but we can reduce the leak by passing a list to pool.map instead of a ndarray.
`images_converted = pool.map(rgb2hsv, [i for i in imgs])`

This consistently reduces memory leak in my tests.

OLD ANSWER:

It does not seems there is a problem in pool. You should not expect "del pool" on line 31 to free your memory, since what is occupying it are the variables "imgs" and "images_converted". These are in the scope of the function "parallel_convert_all_to_hsv" and not in the scope of "rgb2hsv", so "del pool" is not related to them.

The memory is corrected released after deleting "images" and "images_converted" in lines 56 and 59.

Comment: That's not correct. Look at the difference in memory profiling between the sequential version (second run) and multiprocessing (first run): at line 39, the sequential run collects 1.4GB (down to 3GB) while the concurrent collects 400MB (only down to 4GB). As a result, from line 51 onwards the multiprocessing code consistently consumes 1GB more than the sequential version until the program terminates. Locally I parametrized on a Pool class (to avoid having to edit anything), and both a sequential and a threaded "pool" behave properly, only the multiprocessing pool leaks memory.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your sequential output, and so, I ran it locally. Since I am low in RAM memory, I've used smaller images. Now I've notice that there is a memory leak that depends on the size and number of images. If I use 700 images of size (30,300,3), the concurrent version collects nearly the same as the sequential version in line 39. What is more surprising is that if we use 70 images of size (300,300,3) the concurrent version has memory leaks again.

Answer (score 0):

As `multithreading.Pool` is not able to free up memory of around 1* Gb, I have also tried replacing it with `ThreadPool` but no better. I am still wondering about this memory leak problem inside Pools.

This may not be the best solution but can be a work-around solution.

By not using `ThreadPool` or `ProcessPool`, I am creating Threads or Processes manually and assigning each with the image to convert to HSV. Well, I have commented the line `p = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_hsv, args=(imgs[j], shared_list))` because it will spawn new process for each image conversion which I think will be overkill and much expensive than Threads. Obviously, creating threads manually will take some more time (9 sec **without memory leak**) than `ThreadPool` (4 sec but **with memory leak**) but as you can see it almost remains calm on memory.

Here is my code:

```
import multiprocessing
import os
import threading
import time
from memory_profiler import profile
import numpy as np
from skimage.color import rgb2hsv


def do_hsv(img, shared_list):
    shared_list.append(rgb2hsv(img))
    # print("Converted by process {} having parent process {}".format(os.getpid(), os.getppid()))


@profile
def parallel_convert_all_to_hsv(imgs, shared_list):

    cores = os.cpu_count()

    starttime = time.time()

    for i in range(0, len(imgs), cores):

        # print("i :", i)

        jobs = []; pipes = []

        end = i + cores if (i + cores) <= len(imgs) else i + len(imgs[i : -1]) + 1

        # print("end :", end)

        for j in range(i, end):
            # print("j :", j)

            # p = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_hsv, args=(imgs[j], shared_list))
            p = threading.Thread(target= do_hsv, args=(imgs[j], shared_list))

            jobs.append(p)

        for p in jobs: p.start()

        for proc in jobs:
            proc.join()

    print("Took {} seconds to complete ".format(starttime - time.time()))
    return 1

@profile
def doit():

    print("create random images")

    max_images = 700

    images = np.random.rand(max_images, 300, 300,3)

    # images = [x for x in range(0, 10000)]
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    shared_list = manager.list()

    parallel_convert_all_to_hsv(images, shared_list)

    del images

    del shared_list

    print()


doit()
```

Here is the Output:

```
create random images
Took -9.085552453994751 seconds to complete 
Filename: MemoryNotFreed.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    15   1549.1 MiB   1549.1 MiB   @profile
    16                             def parallel_convert_all_to_hsv(imgs, shared_list):
    17                             
    18   1549.1 MiB      0.0 MiB       cores = os.cpu_count()
    19                             
    20   1549.1 MiB      0.0 MiB       starttime = time.time()
    21                             
    22   1566.4 MiB      0.0 MiB       for i in range(0, len(imgs), cores):
    23                             
    24                                     # print("i :", i)
    25                             
    26   1566.4 MiB      0.0 MiB           jobs = []; pipes = []
    27                             
    28   1566.4 MiB      0.0 MiB           end = i + cores if (i + cores) <= len(imgs) else i + len(imgs[i : -1]) + 1
    29                             
    30                                     # print("end :", end)
    31                             
    32   1566.4 MiB      0.0 MiB           for j in range(i, end):
    33                                         # print("j :", j)
    34                             
    35                                         # p = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_hsv, args=(imgs[j], shared_list))
    36   1566.4 MiB      0.0 MiB               p = threading.Thread(target= do_hsv, args=(imgs[j], shared_list))
    37                             
    38   1566.4 MiB      0.0 MiB               jobs.append(p)
    39                             
    40   1566.4 MiB      0.8 MiB           for p in jobs: p.start()
    41                             
    42   1574.9 MiB      1.0 MiB           for proc in jobs:
    43   1574.9 MiB     13.5 MiB               proc.join()
    44                             
    45   1563.5 MiB      0.0 MiB       print("Took {} seconds to complete ".format(starttime - time.time()))
    46   1563.5 MiB      0.0 MiB       return 1



Filename: MemoryNotFreed.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    48    106.6 MiB    106.6 MiB   @profile
    49                             def doit():
    50                             
    51    106.6 MiB      0.0 MiB       print("create random images")
    52                             
    53    106.6 MiB      0.0 MiB       max_images = 700
    54                             
    55   1548.7 MiB   1442.1 MiB       images = np.random.rand(max_images, 300, 300,3)
    56                             
    57                                 # images = [x for x in range(0, 10000)]
    58   1549.0 MiB      0.3 MiB       manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    59   1549.1 MiB      0.0 MiB       shared_list = manager.list()
    60                             
    61   1563.5 MiB     14.5 MiB       parallel_convert_all_to_hsv(images, shared_list)
    62                             
    63    121.6 MiB      0.0 MiB       del images
    64                             
    65    121.6 MiB      0.0 MiB       del shared_list
    66                             
    67    121.6 MiB      0.0 MiB       print()
```