# Python Multiprocess good practices

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

i am working on a software which is treating a lot of data, so we've used multiproccess to accelerate the treatment. here is my actual code :

```
for file_to_process in file_partition:
    if (len(file_to_process) > 0):
       logger = self.__get_logger__(task.lower(), len(proc_list) + 1)
       proc = Process(target=self.__launch_thread__, args=(task, manager_class, file_to_process, list_action, str_target_path, str_target_buffer_path, logger))
       proc.start()
       proc_list.append(proc)

for proc in proc_list:
    proc.join()
```

The thing is that we've noticed that our procs are not realasing memory after they are finished so i was thinking about doing :

```
for file_to_process in file_partition:
    if (len(file_to_process) > 0):
       logger = self.__get_logger__(task.lower(), len(proc_list) + 1)
       proc = Process(target=self.__launch_thread__, args=(task, manager_class, file_to_process, list_action, str_target_path, str_target_buffer_path, logger))
       proc.start()
       proc_list.append(proc)

for proc in proc_list:
    if(!(proc.is_alive())):
        proc.close()
```

I've also seen i could use pool but i am not sure about the interest of using it. I am also not really sure about how the join() method works, i've read the docs but it seems that procs don't really wait for each other.

So if someone can enlight me on how to use this multiprocess lib properly that would be great

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python multiprocessing - How to release memory when a process is done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648967/python-multiprocessing-how-to-release-memory-when-a-process-is-done)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code for `Process`, it will generate the following error message if the right condition is not met:

> Cannot close a process while it is still running. You should first call join() or terminate().

So simply modify your existing code to be:

```
for proc in proc_list:
    proc.join()
    proc.close()
```

Whether that will help much is to be decided.

Comment: ok so i have this error don't undestand why : `proc.close()
AttributeError: 'Process' object has no attribute 'close'`

Comment: `Process.close` is *New in version 3.7* according to the documentation. What version of Python are you running?

Comment: What is 306? There seems to be a decimal point missing. Try: `import sys: print(sys.version)`

Comment: it was 3.6 sorry ! i've tried to use proc.terminate() which compiles but it doesn't resolve my memory leak issu

Comment: `join` waits for the process to end while `terminate` will force the process to end, which is *not* what you want. Well, since you cannot issue a call to `close` in this case, you will have to try to figure out what your process is doing that is resulting in leaving memory unreleased if you really care.